# String.split issue in listView

Tags: android, arrays, string, list, listview

I'm trying to read the contents of a text file into a list view. 
The text file is in the format

```
Item 1
Subitem1 | Subitem2 | Subitem3

Item 2 
Subitem1 | Subitem 2 | Subitem3

Item 3
Subitem1 | Subitem2 | Subitem3
```

This is the logic I used. 
Search file for specific item

```
  while(scanner.hasNextLine())
  {    
     line=scanner.next line();
     if(query.equals(line))
     line = scanner.next line();
  }
  return line;
```

Take the returned line value and split it into String []

```
  String[] myArray = returnedLine.split("|");
```

Convert this into List for the list view

```
  List<String> disp = new ArrayList<String>();
  disp = Arrays.as list(myArray);
```

The code works.  However, the contents of the list view looks weird, with each alphabet in a new listView row. S on one row, u one the next, followed by b, I, t, e, m and 1. All on separate rows

Comment: Also, I just checked. Whatever the query string is, the return value is always the last line of the file ie, subitema of item 3

Comment: @DevOfZot's answer looks good to me and I think this second problem is because you probably want to do a `break;` instead of the second `line = scanner.nextLine();` in your while loop.

Comment: I'll have to add the break after scanner.nextLine(); since I want the return to be the line AFTER the item

Comment: Edit : nope. Break doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want to do?  Don't you just want to exit when you've found the line that matches query? Without all your code it's difficult to be sure what you're doing, but in any case your existing code risks a `NoSuchElementException` as you're calling `scanner.nextLine()` without checking `scanner.hasNextLine()` for the second call to `scanner.nextLine()`

Comment: Yes. I'm sure that's what I wanna do. I can add the scanner.hasNextLine(), but that won't help much with the current dillemma

Comment: I suspect your `if` statement is never matching (i.e. `scanner` is never equal to `line`). Try putting a breakpoint on it and running it in the debugger.  Are you sure you don't have any spaces on the end of your lines and that the case of your search text matches the input file?

Comment: You're right. It's not matching. Any idea why? No whitespaces and I tried equalsIgnoreCase(). No luck

Comment: I'd run it in the debugger and look at the value of `query` and check the value of `line` each time through the loop if your data set is small like the example. Then you'll probably spot what the problem is.

Comment: Try using query.compareTo() instead of query.equals().  Also, using query.trim() to get rid of any whitespace at the beginning or end of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The String.split() function takes a regular expression, not a character, and pipe is a special character in regex.  Try this:

```
String[] myArray = returnedLine.split("\\|");
```

edit: as flightplanner pointer out, your while should probably look like this:

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine())
{    
    line=scanner.next line();
    if(query.equals(line)) {
        line=scanner.next line();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about the other issue? It always returns the last line of the file

Comment: See flightplanner's comment.  You probably only want to call scanner.nextLine() once in the while() statement.

Comment: Basically, the string query will be, for example, item 1. When it finds it, it should read the next line @DevOfZot